# Why do I need to use an offset when I use Arrays.binarySearch?

Tags: java, binary-search, insertion-sort

Why `1` is added to `Array.binarySearch(array, 0, i, x) + 1)`?

```
class GFG 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        final int[] arr = {37, 23, 0, 17, 12, 72, 31, 
                             46, 100, 88, 54 }; 
  
        new GFG().sort(arr); 
  
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 
    } 
  
    public void sort(int array[]) 
    { 
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) 
        { 
            int x = array[i]; 
  
            //Find location to insert using binary search 
            int j = Math.abs(Arrays.binarySearch(array, 0, i, x) + 1); 
  
            //Shifting array to one location right 
            System.arraycopy(array, j, array, j+1, i-j); 
  
            //Placing element at its correct location 
            array[j] = x; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int))

> Returns:
> index of the search key, if it is contained in the array within the specified range; otherwise, `(-(insertion point) - 1)`. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element in the range greater than the key, or toIndex if all elements in the range are less than the specified key.

So there are two cases:

- if the element is found, +1 simply results in inserting the duplicate after the existing element, and the `abs()` does not do anything
- if the element is not a duplicate, the +1 actually undoes the -1 in the highlighted expression above, and the `abs()` makes it non-negative